# How do i throw a redirect in Laravel Controller if the value doesn't exist in the database?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dropdown category select tag that stores the session and matches the session name to the category slug that stored in the database. Everything works well but if a category name that doesn't exist in the database i get this error `Trying to get property 'catslug' of non-object`. How do i fix this problem here my code:

```
 public function catbusiness(Request $request, $slug)
    {
       //this grabs all category in select tag
       $cats =  Category::orderBy('categoryname','ASC')->get();

        //this is the slug for individual category in url
        $catbread = Category::where('catslug', $slug)->first();

        session()->put('categoryname', $catbread->catslug);

        ->with('catbread', $catbread)

    }
```

view.blade.php

```
<select name="record" style="margin-top:5%;">
                    @foreach($cats as $categoryselect)
                    <option value="{{ $categoryselect->catslug  }}"
                        @if(session('categoryname') == $categoryselect->catslug)
                            selected="selected"
                        @endif >
                        {{ $categoryselect->categoryname }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
```

Comment: I think you are using write code wrong  code `->with('catbread', $catbread)` this line is incomplete and where did you pass `$cats` variable you are accessing it in `@foreach($cats as $categoryselect)`

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta ok so catbread matches the slug so it grabbing that category cats is the drop down select of all the categories so if a category dont exist i want to throw a redirect

Comment: in the controller, you want redirect function?

Comment: You can do this automatically with `Category::where('catslug', $slug)->firstOrFail()`. That will automatically throw a 404 if the slug doesn't exist.

Comment: @jfadich oh ok that makes sense thanks

Comment: @jfadich your way does makes sense because it throws the 404 page thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a category exists by using the `exists()` method like this:

```
if(!Category::where('catslug', $slug)->exists()) //Check if the category exists.
{
    return redirect()->route('your_not_found_route'); //Make a redirect
}
$catbread = Category::where('catslug', $slug)->first(); //If category exists fetch its data
```

Comment: this what exactly what i was looking for thank you! @yak0d3

Comment: You shouldn't do a redirect for not found. This will return a 301 redirect when what you want is a 404 response.

Comment: This also executes two SQL queries when it could be done in one. You can grab the category with `$catbread = Category::where('catslug', $slug)->first()` then check if it actually returned anything with `if( ! $catbread ) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: @jfadich there is multiple other options, `firstOrFail` method is also one of these options

Comment: @yak0d3 Read my comment above. I already called that out as an option.